# Cycles of length $2^n - 2$ in the De Bruijn graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, determinants, enumerative-combinatorics

It is well known that the number of (cyclic) [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) is $2^{2^{n-1}-n}$.  This number may also be interpreted as the number of cycles of length $2^n$ in the [De Bruijn graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) of order $n$.

In Section 2c of Fredricksen's paper [A survey of full length nonlinear shift register cycle
algorithms](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1024041) (*SIAM Review* **24** (1982), 195–221), he states a result that he attributes to "Kibler, personal communication, 1972":

> **Theorem.** The number of cycles of length $2^n-2$ in the De Bruijn graph of order $n$ is ${1\over 3}(2^{2^n-2n})(2^{n-1} + (-1)^n)$.

However, he gives only the bare outline of a proof.  By appealing to the [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem), he reduces the calculation to a determinant evaluation, and then simply says, "By induction, the determinant can be evaluated."  However, I don't see how to do this.

Can someone explain how to evaluate the determinant, or give an alternative proof of the above fact?

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: @SteveHuntsman : I have not; that's an interesting suggestion---thanks!